# Python: how to store class variable value instead of the address to that variable?

Tags: python, oop, memory-address, python-class

I have a class that store a `numpy` array and the class has a method to modify the array

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.Matrix = matrix
    def modify(self):
         self.Matrix *= 2

obj = A(someMatrix)
```

Now here's the ridiculous part

```
p = obj.Matrix
obj.modify()
q = obj.Matrix

p - q  # this is the 0 matrix !!!
```

So I realized p and q must be storing the same address (to `obj.Matrix`) but this is clearly **not** what I am trying to do: I wanted to take the difference between the matrix before and after it's been updated!

Then I did this

```
p = np.array(obj.Matrix)
obj.modify()
q = np.array(obj.Matrix)

p - q  # worked
```

But if I do

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.k = 1
    def mod(self):
        self.k *= 2

a = A()

p = a.k
a.mod()
q = a.k

print(p,q) # p = 1, q = 2
```

But how do I solve this problem in general: how do I store the value of the object variable/attribute rather than the address to the variable??

Thank you a ton!

Comment: Everything acts as a reference in Python. What you are asking is "how do I copy a numpy array". The answer is to use the `.copy` method

Comment: Note, that isn't very "rediculous", that is the standard semantics you would expect and it works the same in Java, JavaScript, Ruby etc

Answer (score 0):

Code-specific answer:

`p` and `q` point to the same object because `self.Matrix *= 2` is an inplace-operation that *mutates* `self.Matrix`. (Under the hood, `self.Matrix.__imul__` is called.) You could change the line to `self.Matrix = self.Matrix * 2`, which creates a new matrix and then rebinds `self.Matrix`. (Under the hood, `self.Matrix.__mul__` is called.)

General answer:

Variables/names/identifiers (same thing) are just labels for objects. You need the correct mental model to avoid surprises, I suggest that you start with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns) excellent talk by Ned Batchelder.

Whenever you do

```
a = some_object
b = a
a.mutate()
```

the mutation will be seen across all names, because there has only ever been one object in memory. Assignment NEVER copies data. You need to copy the data explicitly, for example through a `copy` method the object in question might have.

Comment: I edited the question to include another case, how come this works but the numpy case doesn't?

Comment: @zmkm because integers don't have `__imul__`, so `*=` falls back to `__mul__`, which creates a new integer and then rebinds the name `self.k`.

Comment: @zmkm and before you ask, yes you have to memorize which data types are mutable and which are not. For builtin mutable types, augmented assignments such as `*=`, `+=`, ... work in-place. (Integers are not mutable.)